# XAML - Text is not showing in my textbox after I styled it

Tags: wpf, xaml, text, styles

So, I styled my TextBoxes in an app that I'm working on, and all of a sudden I can't see any text that I've bound to my TextBoxes. I feel like I'm missing some kind of ContentPresenter. Well anyway, here is the styling.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Value="#FF2F2F2F" Property="Background"/>
                        <Setter Value="White" Property="Foreground"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is how my TextBoxes are set up

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" BorderThickness="1" Text="{Binding VariableName}">
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your hunch is right, you need to have a template part with the name [`PART_ContentHost` inside your `ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068.aspx):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                    x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
    <!-- ... -->
```

This is because the `ControlTemplate` for a `TextBox` requires a part with the name `PART_ContentHost`. You can view the [`ControlTemplate` examples for the built-in controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773) to find out what named template parts are required and what each part must be able to do in order to retain normal functionality.

Comment: @Stylzs05: I read your request as a `Button` because...I don't know why. Try adding a control with a name `PART_ContentHost`.

Comment: Ah, that did it. And THANK GOD for the link you just gave me. I didn't know that list existed.

Comment: It is actually covered in the WPF exam prep book!