# WPF TextBox not displaying text with Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, textbox, resources

so i have a TextBox, and i set a template to it, but i cannot get the text of the TextBox to display. what am i doing wrong, i followed [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902565/xaml-text-is-not-showing-in-my-textbox-after-i-styled-it/38379181) but i still do not have it working.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="txtReg">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Yellow" >
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

TextBox

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtHdrReg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="40" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="10,0" Height="60" Width="260" Text="REG" Style="{ThemeResource txtReg}" />
```

but still the text isn't displaying, any idea???

Comment: Swap `<ControlTemplate>` with `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">`

Comment: i get "Type is not supported in Windows App Project" Error??

Comment: check "PART_ContentHost"'s "Content" property, it need to be set on "TextBoxView"

Comment: Wait, are you doing a Windows App, or WPF? You have WPF as your tag and that's what stood out at first glance was the missing targettype.

Comment: So just to add to that, I'm guessing you're actually working an a UWP app and not WPF, and what you may have done was copy parts of a WPF template into your UWP app in which case I would suggest starting with a default TextBox template for UWP instead, and you'll still have to specify a TargetType for your ControlTemplate but it wouldn't use x:Type and it PART_ContentHost would not be a named PART either anymore.